# How do I configure the various services available on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: 12.04, server, configuration

I've installed 12.04 (server). I'm now trying to configure web sites, emails, services, etc.

How do I do this?

Comment: It seems like this would be a very basic question for a Server OS... Guess it's back to Windows.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like is too vast to attempt to answer in [AskUbuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com) as it differs for each case asked for. However let me attempt to give some overview and  on  what needs to be done and I given a link to "Ubuntu 12.04 server guide" for referring to details on "How To". If any of those are confusing, please post diffe

1. For websites, you need to configure apache.
2. For  email, you need to some thing like postfix configuration (or other email servers you like a different once)
3. To configure  services, you need to review update-rc.d command to change the current default startup and shutdown commands.

For a detailed how to on each of these, please refer to 12.04 server guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/)